# Percolation program compiles but freezes up when running

Tags: java

I wrote a program for the percolation problem for the Coursera Algorithms course. Everything seems to compile successfully, but when I run it in terminal, it just freezes and no output is shown. Is my performance just way too slow, or is there a bug somewhere in my code? Code is posted below, the arguments I use are n = 200 and 100 trials. Thank you so much in advance!

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;

public class Percolation {

    private WeightedQuickUnionUF grid;
    private WeightedQuickUnionUF grid2;
    private boolean[] openSites;
    private int numOpenSites, gridLength, topIndex, bottomIndex;

   public Percolation(int n)   {   
       // create n-by-n grid, with all sites blocked
       if (n <= 0) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       }

       int numNodes = (n * n) + 2;
       grid = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(numNodes);
       grid2 = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(numNodes);
       openSites = new boolean[n * n];
       numOpenSites = 0;
       gridLength = n;
       topIndex = n * n;
       bottomIndex = n * n + 1;
   }

   public    void open(int row, int col)  {  // open site (row, col) if it is not open already 
       //check if row and col are valid 
       if (row < 1 || row > gridLength || col < 1 || col > gridLength) {
           throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
       }
       //if not open, then open
       if (!isOpen(row, col)) {
           openSite(row, col);
           connectTopVirtualSite(row, col);
           connectAdjacentSites(row, col);
           connectBottomVirtualSite(row, col);
           numOpenSites++;
       }
   }

   private void openSite(int row, int col) {
       int index = convertToIndex(row, col);

       //set that site to true
       openSites[index] = true;
   }

   private void connectTopVirtualSite(int row, int col) {
       if (row == 1) {
           grid.union(topIndex, convertToIndex(row, col));
           grid2.union(topIndex, convertToIndex(row, col));
       }
   }

   private void connectAdjacentSites(int row, int col) {
       connectTop(row, col);
       connectLeft(row, col);
       connectRight(row, col);
       connectBottom(row, col);
   }

   private void connectTop(int row, int col) {
       if (row > 1 && isOpen(row - 1, col)) {
           grid.union(convertToIndex(row - 1, col), convertToIndex(row, col));
           grid2.union(convertToIndex(row - 1, col), convertToIndex(row, col));
       }
   }

   private void connectLeft(int row, int col) {
       if (col > 1 && isOpen(row, col - 1)) {
           grid.union(convertToIndex(row, col - 1), convertToIndex(row, col));
           grid2.union(convertToIndex(row, col - 1), convertToIndex(row, col));
       }
   }

   private void connectRight(int row, int col) {
       if (col < gridLength && isOpen(row, col + 1)) {
           grid.union(convertToIndex(row, col), convertToIndex(row, col + 1));
           grid2.union(convertToIndex(row, col), convertToIndex(row, col + 1));
       }
   }

   private void connectBottom(int row, int col) {
       if (row < gridLength && isOpen(row + 1, col)) {
           grid.union(convertToIndex(row, col), convertToIndex(row + 1, col));
           grid2.union(convertToIndex(row, col), convertToIndex(row + 1, col));
       }
   }

   private void connectBottomVirtualSite(int row, int col) {
       if (row == gridLength) {
           grid2.union(convertToIndex(row, col), bottomIndex);
       }
   }

   private int convertToIndex(int row, int col) {
       return gridLength * (row - 1) + (col - 1);
   }

   public boolean isOpen(int row, int col) { // is site (row, col) open?
       if (row < 1 || row > gridLength || col < 1 || col > gridLength) {
           throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
       }
       return openSites[convertToIndex(row, col)];
   }

   public boolean isFull(int row, int col) { // is site (row, col) full?
       if (row < 1 || row > gridLength || col < 1 || col > gridLength) {
           throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
       }
       return grid.connected(convertToIndex(row, col), topIndex);
   }

   public     int numberOfOpenSites()  {     // number of open sites
       return numOpenSites;
   }

   public boolean percolates()  {            // does the system percolate?
       return grid2.connected(topIndex, bottomIndex);
   }

   //public static void main(String[] args)   // test client (optional)
}



import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdStats;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class PercolationStats {

    private double[] results;

    public PercolationStats(int n, int trials) {
        if (n <= 0 || trials <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        results = new double[trials];

        //fill up results with the p values of every trial
        runExperiments(n, trials);
    }

    private void runExperiments(int n, int trials) {
        int row, col;

        for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++) {
            Percolation test = new Percolation(n);
            while (!test.percolates()) {
                //generate new random row and col
                row = StdRandom.uniform(n - 1) + 1;
                col = StdRandom.uniform(n - 1) + 1;
                test.open(row, col);
            }
            results[i] = (double)(test.numberOfOpenSites()) / (n * n);
        }
    }

    public double mean() {
        //return sample mean of all the p values
        return StdStats.mean(results);
    }

    public double stddev() {
        //return sample standard deviation of percolation threshold
        return StdStats.stddev(results);
    }

    public double confidenceLo() {
        return mean() - ((1.96 * stddev()) / sqrt(results.length));
    }

    public double confidenceHi() {
        return mean() + ((1.96 * stddev()) / sqrt(results.length));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PercolationStats test = new PercolationStats(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        System.out.println("mean                     = " + test.mean());
        System.out.println("stddev                   = " + test.stddev());
        System.out.println("95% confidence interval  = [" + test.confidenceLo() + ", " + test.confidenceHi() + "]");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Seems it never percolates. Start with n=2 and debug

Comment: time to start using a debugger!